# WebGL live (animated) histogram

Tags: shader, webgl, textures

I would like to create a histogram of pixel colors for an animated WebGL canvas. This histogram would update as the input updates. (I expect this would be similar to calculating a histogram for a video.)

I found a solution for a static image.

[How to create a histogram in WebGL2 using 16 bit data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015221/how-to-create-a-histogram-in-webgl2-using-16-bit-data)

Using WebGL, would the histogram be able to update at a decent frame rate? The input would be about 2000 by 2000 pixels.